# Bulk delete in oracle database with toad

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have a table with over 24 million log records , now we are trying to reduce that. Due to company policy we aren't allowed to do a truncate , move or anyhting of that sort. The records have to be deleted from that table in one flued go, aprox 23 million rows. I have not much experience in bulk deletes. But i was wondering if there is a way to do this without the regular delete ( which times out even when there are multiple indexes on the tables and where clause). I think a bulk remove would do the trick but i have no experience with this. I tried to look into a cursor that would get all the records i need to delete after a certain date , and then loop over the cursor to delete records. See it as select into cursor x records from y table where date is after y.createdate is after sysdate - 30 , loop cursor delete.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of options you can use:

1. Partition the table on `createdate` and drop the partitions that are older than your 30 day limit.
2. Create a new table using:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE table_name2 AS
   SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE createdate < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY;
   ```

   Copy the constraints, etc. from the old table and then drop the old table and rename the new table to the old table.
3. If you cannot delete 21 million rows in one go then split it up into smaller batches:

   ```sql
   DELETE FROM table_name
   WHERE ROWID IN (
     SELECT ROWID
     FROM   table_name
     WHERE  createdate < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY
     ORDER BY createdate
     FETCH FIRST 1000000 ROWS ONLY
   );
   ```

   and incrementally remove all the rows.

Comment: I've had this as a solution myself but they client won't accept that for some reason. We tried to reason with them on that point put they won't accept. They want all the requested data from the table to be deleted without a clone or copy mechanism or changed names.

Comment: @BrianNeyens Then partition the table and drop the partitions you don't want.

Comment: yes that exactly the case , it's not about what i want , i would just select into a new table , truncate the current one and then insert into from new table. The client doesn't want any data to be copied anywhere , nothing to be truncated , nothing to be changed to the database system or table except for the fact that about 21 million records have to be deleted in the fastest way possible. Normal delete with a where clausule doesn't work , because the redo memory would get overloaded.

Comment: what's the issue with deleting them in chunks as mentioned in the answer? or you may make use of multiple cores using the dbms_parallel_execute package if PLSQL code is allowed to use.